# Does Coleman-de Luccia instanton approach a Hawking-Moss instanton?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, instantons

Suppose a Coleman-de Luccia instanton terminates in the basin with the true vacuum between the top of the potential barrier and the field value with potential energy equal to the potential energy of the false vacuum.

Is the Euclidean action $S_{\text{E,bubble}}$ ever much different than $S_{\text{E,HM}}$, where $S_{\text{E,HM}}$ is the evaluated for a configuration in which the field sits atop the potential barrier everywhere and for all time (a Hawking-Moss instanton)?  Can I take the $\exp(S_{\text{E,fv}} - S_{\text{E,HM}})$ as a rough estimate of the transition rate for such an CDL instanton, or could the true rate vary by orders of magnitude from that value?